# UPDATE form modal bootstrap in codeigniter using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Been struggling with this for about few hours. I'm attempting to have a modal drop down (Twitter bootstrap modal) that contains a form to choose a category of user. This is built in CodeIgniter. But when i try to save form's value using AJAX, the `SUCCESS` function won't run without `alert()`. I'm sorry for my bad grammar, i hope you can understand what i mean.
i need for your help...

view (kasir_halaman.php):

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Ubah Kasir</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="#" id="editform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Nama</label>&nbsp;<span class="error" id="report1"></span>
                            <input type="text" id="editnama" name="nama" class="form-control" maxlength="100" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>E-mail</label>
                            <input type="email" id="editemail" name="email" class="form-control" maxlength="150" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Kategori</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="kategoripetugas" id="editkategori" required>
                                <option value=""> -- Pilih Kategori -- </option>
                                <option value="1">Admin</option>
                                <option value="2">Kasir</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;">Simpan</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

controller (kasir.php):

```
public function updatePetugas($id)
{
    $nama_petugas = $this->input->post('nama');
    $email_petugas = $this->input->post('email');
    $kategori_petugas = $this->input->post('kategoripetugas');
    $data = array('nama'=>$nama_petugas, 'email'=>$email_petugas, 'kategori'=>$kategori_petugas);
    $update = $this->Crud->update(array('idpetugas'=>$id), 'petugas', $data);
    if($update){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 2;
    }
}
```

javascript (petugas.js) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var check1=0; var id;
$("#nama").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var nama = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/cekData/kasir/nama/'+nama,
        data:{send:true},
        success:function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $("#report1").text("");
                check1=1;
            }else{
                $("#report1").text("*nama petugas sudah terpakai");
                check1=0;
            }
        }
    });
});

$(".edit").click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/getData/'+id,
        data:{send:true},
        success:function(data){
            $("#editnama").val(data['nama']);
            $("#editemail").val(data['email']);
            $("#editkategori").val(data['kategori']);   
        }
    });
});

$("#editform").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/updatePetugas/'+id,
        data:formData,
        type:'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $("#editModal").hide();
                window.location.reload(true);
            }else if(data==2){
                alert('gagal');
            }
        }
    });
    alert("success!"); // if i remove this alert, the success function won't run or executed
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this a few ways, what is actually happening is that you are submitting the data via ajax as well as submitting the form itself.

using `e` or the event

```
$("#editform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

or by returning `false` on submit

```
 });
    //alert("success!"); we can comment this out because it will work now without the alert holding the page
    return false;
});
```

in either case you can remove your alert.

Comment: Thankyou so much! I appreciate it. Both of them are works. But after update and click submit, Mozilla browser will display "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier". Is there another way to fix this problem without display that notification from Mozilla browser?